# Ajax Autocomplete for jQuery and Extra Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

Looking for some guidance using Ajax Automplete for jQuery (http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery). I've been able to implement it to retrieve a list of schools when the user types, but I would like to include city and state information as a prompt. An example can be found here:

http://www.keuka.edu/pete/Inquiry
(Use the "High School Name" field and type in a local US high school)

I've programmed it to generate the data, but I'm including it as a span in the suggestion field, and it's populating that information in the textbox.

Does anyone have any insights as to how to include the helpful information but have only the name show up in the textbox when the user selects a suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `OnSelect` to replace the textbox value with the data.

From the example provided at the autocomplete project. I added one line.

```
$('#autocomplete-ajax').autocomplete({
            lookup: countriesArray,
            lookupFilter: function(suggestion, originalQuery, queryLowerCase) {
                var re = new RegExp('\\b' + $.Autocomplete.utils.escapeRegExChars(queryLowerCase), 'gi');
                return re.test(suggestion.value);
            },
            onSelect: function(suggestion) {
                $('input#autocomplete-ajax').val(suggestion.data);// REPLACE WITH YOUR DATA
                $('#selction-ajax').html('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
            }
        });
```

The line I want to bring to your attention is:

`$('input#autocomplete-ajax').val(suggestion.data);// REPLACE WITH YOUR DATA`

You can strip the span out of the chosen value.